# Proving that $(\neg Q) \Rightarrow (R \Rightarrow \neg (P \wedge Q))$ is a tautology, by contradiction

Tags: logic

**Problem**

Show that $(\neg Q) \Rightarrow (R \Rightarrow \neg (P \wedge Q))$ is a tautology.

**Progress**

I've shown this using a truth-table, but when asked to show it using contradiction, I'm at a loss.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What goes wrong when you start a bog-standard proof by contradiction? Assume the negation of what you want to prove, and try to derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Assume the statement is false.

Since a conditional can only be false when the antecedent is true and the consequent false, that means that:

$\neg Q$ is true, i.e. $Q$ is false

and

$R \rightarrow \neg (P \land Q)$ is false

And the latter means that:

$R$ is true

and

$\neg (P \land Q)$ is false

hence $P \land Q$ is true, and hence $Q$ is true.

So, $Q$ has to be both true and false: a contradiction!

Since this contradiction was reached under the assumption that the statement is false, apparently the statement can *not* be false. Hence, it is a tautology.

Here is how you can depict that same reasoning process in what is called a 'short truth table':

\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
\neg & Q & \rightarrow & (R & \rightarrow & \neg & (P & \land & Q))\\
\hline
T_2 & \color{red}F_3 & F_1 & T_5 & F_4 & F_6 & T_8 & T_7 & \color{red}T_9\\
\end{array}

(The indices show the order in which truth-values are assigned. The red values show the contradiction reached)